# Select2 widget: width related to parent div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I use Select2 widget to populate dropdown menus in my MVC.NET application. Is it possible to make selection list same width as parent div or parent dropdown? Only thing that I came to is setting `max-width: 300px;` in all the select2 css classes, but that's not quite right for me, because when I click on dropdown, it becomes smaller OR bigger than parent div or dropdown (because of max-width, sure).

How it looks like now:

- http://imageshack.us/a/img836/6984/captureqtj.png
- http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/5261/capture2mu.png

All the css is the same as default only there are `max-width: 300px;` everywhere.

I use [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) to layout site.

**EDIT**

CSS files:

1. http://pastebin.com/2iEgEPmn
2. http://pastebin.com/uhxxYJpr
3. http://pastebin.com/pzbSwNfK

HTML/C# example:

1. http://pastebin.com/DerAzaj0
2. Output source: http://pastebin.com/CJVA4WTP

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show the page so that I can see your css

Comment: Site is not publicly available. It's a business application so I can't let login to our page without my boss' permission. I can, however, post some code of css'es and html.

Comment: Could you please post the outputed HTML

Comment: @YaMo updated. I'm not sure how to give the code that is produced AFTER jQuery call as it is in inspector.